# Reporting Hard / Soft errors in custom activity execute (Journey Builder)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, error, custom-activity

I'm working on a custom activity (NodeJS) for Journey Builder that sends SMS through a third party API. The SMS is sent when the "execute" method is called for each contact.

When something goes wrong, the execute function send a response with a 500 error status (ie: return res.sendStatus(500)).

There is an inconstancy in the report shown on Journey Builder in that case:

[image]

I would expect "Successes" to be 0 and "Hard Errors" to be 1.

How do I report a hard error in my activity? Why is this report inconsistent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug within SFMC. Here is the Known Issue link

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000uY3N4AAK/~